# Структуры и методы

Tags: golang

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему во втором случае не выводится имя телефона?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Person struct {
    Name string
}

func (p *Person) Talk() {
    fmt.Println("Привет, моё имя", p.Name)
}

type Android struct {
    Person
    Model string
}

func main() {
    alex := Person{Name: "Dima"}
    alex.Talk()

    //mobile := new(Android)
    mobile := new(Android)
    mobile.Model = "Asus"
    mobile.Talk()
}
```

Comment: @misha99, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Потому что вы присваиваете имя переменной `Model`, а надо `Name`.

Answer (score 0):

В сообщении выводится .Name, а устанавливаете .Model

В любом случае, одним из методов Person вы не сможете вывести поля, которые устанавливаются для родительской структуры (например .Model), в таком случае придется переопределить метод Talk для нее:

https://play.golang.org/p/_UyGcKqxi00